# I'm trying to split my Excel workbook into multiple workbooks but am having an issue with the code

Tags: excel

I work for a non-profit that runs events. I've been given a large list of registrants, each of whom belong to a specific team. I'm trying to split my large workbook into individual workbooks for each team.

I've been given a code that I've been told has worked in the past, yet I'm having some issues with it. Here's the code itself.

Sub ParseItems()

'Jerry Beaucaire  (4/22/2010)

'Based on selected column, data is filtered to individual workbooks

'workbooks are named for the value plus today's date

Dim LR As Long, Itm As Long, MyCount As Long, vCol As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet, MyArr As Variant, vTitles As String, SvPath As String

'Sheet with data in it

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

'Path to save files into, remember the final \

```
SvPath = "G:\AWNY\NW 2015\Teams\Post DOE\Interim Rosters\” "
```

'Range where titles are across top of data, as string, data MUST

'have titles in this row, edit to suit your titles locale

```
vTitles = "A1:AB1"
```

'Choose column to evaluate from, column A = 1, B = 2, etc.

vCol = Application.InputBox("What column to split data by? " & vbLf & vbLf & "(A=1, B=2, C=3, etc)", "Which column?", 1, Type:=1)

If vCol = 0 Then Exit Sub

'Spot bottom row of data

LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vCol).End(xlUp).Row

'Speed up macro execution

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Get a temporary list of unique values from column A

```
ws.Columns(vCol).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws.Range("EE1"), Unique:=True
```

'Sort the temporary list

```
ws.Columns("EE:EE").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("EE2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

'Put list into an array for looping (values cannot be the result of formulas, must be constants)

```
MyArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("EE2:EE" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
```

'clear temporary worksheet list

```
ws.Range("EE:EE").Clear
```

'Turn on the autofilter, one column only is all that is needed

```
ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter
```

'Loop through list one value at a time

```
For Itm = 1 To UBound(MyArr)

    ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter Field:=vCol, Criteria1:=MyArr(Itm)



    ws.Range("A1:A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy

    Workbooks.Add

    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    Cells.Columns.AutoFit

    MyCount = MyCount + Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1



    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SvPath & MyArr(Itm), 51

    ActiveWorkbook.Close False



    ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter Field:=vCol

Next Itm
```

'Cleanup

```
ws.AutoFilterMode = False

MsgBox "Rows with data: " & (LR - 1) & vbLf & "Rows copied to other sheets: " & MyCount & vbLf & "Hope they match!!"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

The issue I'm having is that, when I run the code and it prompts me to enter which column I want to split the data by. I enter "1" (the team names are in the A column) and it tells me I have a "Run Time Error:'1004'" and that "It cannot be applied to the selected range. Select a single cell in the range and try again".

I'm not sure what to do to fix this and would appreciate any advice!
Thanks!

Comment: Add a space and `_` to the end of that line.  The line below is part of that line and need the continuance.

Comment: @scott Thank you for the help! I tried adding the space and the _ to the end of the line but I'm getting the same error message. I'm wondering if it's because the other lines are still in red, and when I add the _ it stays in black. I apologize for my lack of knowledge, this is my first time attempting this.